# JavaFX fixed button size with dynamic length of text

Tags: button, javafx

I have a problem with my button size in JavaFX. I want to have fixed size buttons but when I change text on the buttons, changes button size aswell.

I have 5 buttons and 5 random numbers between 1 - 20. Buttons with single digit is smaller then buttons with two digits. I want both same size.

What can I do?

Comment: You can implement a container that contains all the buttons, say ButtonPane, and layouts all of them to the maximum preferred width among all the buttons. That is, ButtonPane overrides the `layoutChildren()` method.

Comment: As a special case, if you put your buttons into a `VBox` with `fillWidth=true` (the default), they will all be resized to the width of the `VBox`, i.e. to the same width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do this.  The buttons go in a TilePane, the TilePane goes in a group so that everything in it remains at it's preferred size.  A preferred size is set on each button.

[image: fixed width buttons]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class FixedSizes extends Application {

    private static final int NUM_BUTTONS = 5;
    private static final int MAX_BUTTON_VALUE = 20;
    private static final Random random = new Random(42);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(generateButtonLayout()));
        stage.show();
    }

    private Parent generateButtonLayout() {
        TilePane layout = new TilePane();
        layout.setHgap(10);
        layout.setPrefColumns(NUM_BUTTONS);
        layout.getChildren().setAll(createButtons());
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        return new Group(layout);
    }

    private Button[] createButtons() {
        Button[] buttons = new Button[NUM_BUTTONS];
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i] = createButton();
        }

        return buttons;
    }

    private Button createButton() {
        Button button = new Button(generateButtonText());
        button.setOnAction(event -> button.setText(generateButtonText()));
        button.setPrefWidth(50);

        return button;
    }

    private String generateButtonText() {
        return "" + (random.nextInt(MAX_BUTTON_VALUE) + 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```